# How the application architecture should be, if we want to use atmosphere-jersey for websockets?

Tags: java, angularjs, atmosphere

I'm new to this, and trying to understand & implement atmosphere-jersey for my POC: TODO app. I'm not sure whether my architecture is right or wrong. Want to know how could be the architecture of my web application.

Client side I'm using angular.js and serverside just atmosphere-jersey.

My TODO app contains, Teams & TODO's.

- If anyone creates a team, it should be pushed/broadcast to all the logged users
- If anyone creates TODO item in a team, it should broadcast to only those members of team

So started with LoginService

- Client makes first request to a LoginLogoutService in which it checks user credentials. Here I could do with simple http request and could save userObject in HttpSession, but for AtmosphereServices objects stored in HttpSession are not available. So im using atmosphere-websocket-request.

  ```
  var request = {
  url: 'atm/loginLogoutService/login?' + queryString,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  logLevel: 'debug',
  transport: 'websocket',
  trackMessageLength: true,
  shared: true,
  fallbackTransport: 'long-polling'
  };
  ```
- If he is an authorized user, then In suspend method I'm creating a session(by storing its uuid in a ConcurrentMap) and setting an attribute: userObject in AtmosphereResource

  ```
  @Path("login")
  @Suspend(contentType = "application/json", listeners = {OnDisconnect.class})
  @GET
  public String suspend(
                  @Context AtmosphereResource resource,
                  @QueryParam("sessionId") String sessionId,
                  @QueryParam("userId") int userId,
                  @QueryParam("password") String password,
                  @QueryParam("fullname") String fullName
  ) {
          try {
                  UserManager um = new UserManager();
                  UserData loginAtemptByUser = null;
                  if (fullName == null || "".equalsIgnoreCase(fullName)) {
                          logger.debug("Checking from DB...");
                          loginAtemptByUser = um.authenticateUser(userId, password);
                          if (loginAtemptByUser != null) {
                                  logger.debug("Authorised user logged in.");
                                  createSession(resource);
                                  setAttribute(resource, USER_IN_SESSION_ATTR, loginAtemptByUser);
                                  responseJSON.put(KEY_LOGIN_STATUS, VAL_LOGIN_SUCCESS);
                                  responseJSON.put(ATMOSPHERE_UUID, resource.uuid());
                                  responseJSON.put(KEY_REQ_MSG, loginAtemptByUser.getFullName());
                          } else {
                                  logger.debug("No match found with username & password");
                          }
                          responseJSON.put(KEY_REQ_STATUS, VAL_REQ_STATUS_SUCCESS);
                  }
          } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                  responseJSON.put(KEY_REQ_STATUS, VAL_REQ_STATUS_ERROR);
                  responseJSON.put(KEY_REQ_MSG, "Invalid data, please check");
          } catch (JSONException e) {
                  responseJSON.put(KEY_REQ_STATUS, VAL_REQ_STATUS_ERROR);
                  responseJSON.put(KEY_REQ_MSG, "Error occured, please try again later");
          }
          return responseJSON.toString();
  }
  ```
- On client side, I could get the responseJSON in onMessage function and I could do the necessary things.

  ```
  request.onMessage = function(response) {
      console.info("onMessage : " + 'response.responseBody: ' + response.responseBody)
  }
  ```
- Now when the user clicks on teams tab, again I'm making atmosphere web-socket request by sending uuid which we got from loginLogoutService as follows. (can we use the existing one? If yes, how?)

  ```
  var request = {
  url: 'atm/teamsService?uuid='+$rootScope.uuid, //this is angularJs, uuid is stored in a variable called "$rootScope.uuid"
  contentType: 'application/json',
  logLevel: 'debug',
  transport: 'websocket',
  trackMessageLength: false,
  reconnectInterval: 5000,
  enableXDR: true,
  timeout: 60000,
  fallbackTransport: 'long-polling',
  };
  ```
- In the TeamsService, suspend method, I could get the uuid, can checks if it exists in ConcurrentMap. If it exists, sending back all the teams that are created before.

  ```
  @Suspend(contentType = "application/json", listeners = {OnDisconnect.class})
  @GET
  public String suspend(
                  @QueryParam("uuid") String uuid
  ) {

          logger.info("Request to suspend for Teams with uuid - " + uuid);
          if (isSessionInitialized(uuid)) {
                  logger.info("Retriving All teams for a newly connected user");
                  List<Teams> list = new TeamsManager().retriveAllTeams();

                  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                  JSONObject teams = null;
                  JSONObject teamsWithMembersCount = null;
                  for (Teams team : list) {
                          teams = new JSONObject();
                          teamsWithMembersCount = new JSONObject();
                          teams.put("teamId", team.getTeamId());
                          teams.put("teamName", team.getTeamName());
                          teamsWithMembersCount.put("membersCount", 0);
                          teamsWithMembersCount.put("teams", teams);
                          jsonArray.put(teamsWithMembersCount);
                  }
                  return jsonArray.toString();
          } else {
                  logger.info("uuid is not in atmosphere session");
                  return "";
          }
  }
  ```
- Now when the user creates a team from UI, Im pushing data to server broadcaster

  ```
  $scope.addTeam = function() {
     socket.push(jQuery.stringifyJSON({teamId: 1, teamName: $scope.newTeam}));
     $scope.newTeam = "";
  };
  ```
- Here is my broadcaster in TeamsService

  ```
  @Broadcast(writeEntity = true)
  @POST
  @Produces("application/json")
  public TeamsResponse broadcast(
                  @QueryParam("uuid") String uuid,
                  Teams team) {
          printSessionsByUuidMap();
          logger.debug("Request to create new team - " + uuid);
          UserData ud = null;
          TeamsResponse teamRes = null;
          try {
                  ud = (UserData) getAttribute(uuid, USER_IN_SESSION_ATTR);
                  logger.debug("session------->>>> " + ud.getFullName());
          } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
          }
          if (ud != null) {
                  TeamsManager tm = new TeamsManager();
                  teamRes = new TeamsResponse(team, 0);
                  Teams teamToSave = new Teams();
                  teamToSave.setTeamName(team.getTeamName());
                  if (tm.createTeam(teamToSave, ud)) {
                          teamRes = new TeamsResponse(team, 0);
                  }
          }else{
                  logger.debug("Could'nt get current user from atmosphere session ");
          }

          return teamRes;
  }
  ```

**Everything is working. but I don't know, whether I'm doing right or wrong**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is an [option to use/track sessions in Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Enabling-HttpSession-Support) I would suggest that you don't use WebSockets for all transactions with the server, just for the server-side notifications.

Comment: Thanks to look at my question. I will consider your point for not to use all transactions. but to notify all users that a team has been created by X-user, I need to store userDetails in session, and I should use websockets. I will try to redesign and my architecture. Could you please provide me any links?

Comment: I don't know the Atmosphere framework, but you need cross-session notifications so storing the user details on a single session isn't enough - you need to have a service/class that knows about all sessions that are connected right now (and gets notified when they are disconnected).

Comment: Yes, I have all those. I have a BaseService, in which all the session are handled. And each service also listens to onDisconnect class, where I will get notified. I want to know, whether I should have only one websocket connect with the server or I should have multiple connections